# Enable code hot swapping in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, debugging, libgdx, hotswap

I'm currently learning **LibGDX** using **Android Studio** as my IDE, and I have a question regarding the `code hot swapping` feature in the context of a project created with **LibGDX**.

I've noticed that when using the `Android Launcher` in my project, I have the option to use the `Apply Code Changes` and `Apply Code Changes and Restart Activity` features, which allow me to quickly apply code changes without restarting the entire application. However, when I use the `Desktop Launcher`, these features are not active. I would like to have the ability to use `Apply Code Changes` and `Apply Code Changes and Restart Activity` with the `Desktop Launcher`, as it would be convenient for desktop testing.

I am using **Android Studio Giraffe 2022.3.1**, **SDK 33**, **JBR 17** and **LibGDX 1.12.0**.

I would greatly appreciate any assistance or advice on this matter. Thank you!

Someone had previously asked about a similar issue, and they were told that "hot swap debugging does not appear to work when using the Gradle templat", but that was 9 years ago. There might have been some changes since then.
I've already examined all the settings and found only `File` > `Settings` > `Build, Execution, Deployment` > `Debugger` > `HotSwap`. I've also attempted to use key combinations like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd>, but none of these methods seem to work.

Comment: I haven't tried it, but I'm highly doubtful hot swapping would work in a game, which makes heavy use of native memory and JNI.

Comment: I asked a similar question about enabling hot swapping to Orange Pixel on one of his YouTube videos and replied as follows: "Try running it through  intellij /ide , and not through Gradle. That fixed it for me" it didn't work for me but I'm also not sure I understood him correctly

Answer (score 0):

Hot Swap should work in the Desktop build, but you'll need to disable the Android Plugins for it to work. If you don't do this then you will get an `Unable to delete directory` error.

[image: Delete Plugin Screen]